# Populate HardCode No Value" if table is blank

Tags: mysql

i ma having a table test with a single column 'Name'. if want to populate hard code string "No Value" if my table is blank,if table is not blank then simply display all the data(that we do using 'Select').

Comment: Edit your question with post that you have tried and error if you got

Answer (score 0):

If the table is empty, then you want to see `'No Value'`, otherwise the contents.  Normally, you would do this in the application layer.  But here is a way to do it in SQL:

```
select (case when count(*) = 0 then 'No Value' end)
from table t
having count(*) = 0
union all
select name
from table t;
```

The `count(*)` is needed in the first query to make it an aggregation query.